# Meaning of "end up a noun"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am watching 13 Reasons Why with Korean subtitles, and have a question about a pharse, *end up*.
These are the lines:

> A:I had this friend, Amy. I told her everything, including my series of embarrassing sex dreams featuring various Avengers,including Scarlett Johansson. Then one day, you know,the moving trucks come. I'm like, "Bye! Don't tell anyoneabout that Scarlett Johansson thing!"But she posts about it because that's the only communication you have anymore.
>
> B:And it ends up getting around your new school.
>
> A:And gets completely twisted.
>
> B: **So you end up That Girl.**
>
> A: **I am so That Girl.**
>
> B: I'm That Other Girl.
>   [show=13-reasons-why-2017&episode=s01e02](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=13-reasons-why-2017&episode=s01e02)

I would like to know what does "end up" mean here.

Does it mean "end up **with**"? or "end up **as**"?

I think it seems like "so you became That Girl" (so you end up **as** that girl),

but the subtitles say "so you finished the relationship with that girl".
But since the next line says "I am so That Girl", it seems weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "So you end up That Girl."

It's very colloquial, & the translation is wrong [unless there is some other context not apparent from the extract].

To 'end up' is in effect to 'become'.
It implies the result of the transition, the end... if you spend all your money all the time, you will end up broke.

"So you become that girl" or "So you become like that girl" as it's not really saying you will physically turn into the other person, just that you will be perceived in the same way.

Note that [& I need a real grammarian to tell me why] it is 'become' not 'became'. It's present tense; which matches all before it - "B:And it ends up..." "A: And gets..."
I'd call it some kind of 'present continuous' sense, but I really am no grammarian, so we may need some confirmation on that point.

Probably, to a native, they would see the implied 'being like' in the original sentence - "So you end up being like that girl."